# In python, why slicing doesn't work in readline()?

Tags: python, slice, readfile, readline

First, I have a file named "words.txt" with several words(apple noon tea water).
and I want to make some code to check if there is a word that is a palindrome(noon).

my code is:

```
with open('words.txt','r') as file:
    line = None
    while line !='':
        line = file.readline()
        
        if line == line[::-1]:
            print(line.strip('\n'))

        else :
            pass
```

but code doesn't work as my intent, It looks like If condition is being ignored

I don'n know why this happens. I need your help
Thx

Comment: The condition `line == line[::-1]` won't be `True` in general, because `line` has `'\n'` at the end. Instead, try `line = file.readline().rstrip('\n')`.

Comment: oh I figured out why, and fixed the code. thanks for the help